# iPhone Objective-C: Exact same method call, working the first time, but getting "unrecognized selector" the second

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am working with a UITableViewController. The method that fails is:

```
- (void) testLoc {
    self.dictionary = [self.delegate getLocationsWithLatitude:@"0.0" longitude:@"0.0"]; //HERE
    [self setUpTableArray:dictionary]; 
}
```

Test results have shown that the exception is thrown in the first line of `testLoc`.

```
- (NSDictionary *) getLocationsWithLatitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude;
```

All I do in the above method is make an HTTP request and return an NSDictionary.

Below is my viewDidLoad (the first method call, which works) for the UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self testLoc];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And here is my viewWillAppear, which I get "unrecognized selector" from:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [self testLoc];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
-[NSCFString key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x141770
```

The reason I am doing this is because I have a table view that I want to update every time I tab back to it with a tab bar.

This is for the first real app that I am building, and I would really appreciate any kind of insight. Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

Here is getLocationsWithLatitude:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getLocationsWithLatitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude {
OAMutableURLRequest *locationsRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somerequesturl"] 
                                                                        consumer:self.globals.consumer 
                                                                           token:self.globals.requestToken 
                                                                           realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];
[locationsRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[locationsRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"geolat" value:latitude],
                                 [OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"geolong" value:longitude],
                                 nil]];

[locationsRequest prepare];
NSData *locationsData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:locationsRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *locationsString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:locationsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    [locationsRequest release];
    SBJSON *jsonParser = [SBJSON new];
    NSError *error = nil;
    return [jsonParser objectWithString:locationsString error:&error]; 
}
```

Here is setUpTableArray:

```
- (void) setUpTableArray:(NSDictionary *)dict {

    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"groups"];
    if (array != nil) {
        self.placesArray = array;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you show us the actual exception

Comment: @freespace I just updated my question with the error. Thanks!

Comment: You need to post the code of `setUpTableArray` and `getLocationWithLatitute:Longitute:`.

Comment: @Yuji setUpTableArray and getLocationWithLatitude are now posted.

Comment: Ugh, the problem might be inside `SBJSON`... Could you check what's returned by `jsonParser`? Is it really returning a dictionary?

Comment: Also, when you see the `unrecognized selector` error, the stack trace should also be shown there, i.e. which sequence of method calls triggered the error. That contains the info where the error occurred. The error means that you called a method `key` on an `NSString`. That might have occurred because `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` contained an object whose class is different from what you expected.

Comment: Gah, I just found my own error. Such a stupid little mistake too.

Comment: Also, +1 for asking me to post getLocationWIthLatitude. In my mind, I was so sure everything was fine in that method.

Comment: Nevermind, locationsString is auto-released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I definitely found my own problem this time. Just get rid of `[locationsRequest prepare];` I definitely saw code somewhere that has that, but [this](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer) tells me otherwise.

**EDIT**
Turns out this was a memory-memory allocation error. Getting rid of that line wasn't the actual fix. It seems to be some problem with a string being auto-released. I asked a follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270071/nsstring-string-somestring-vs-nsstring-string-nsstring-alloc-initwith).

Comment: Good you figured that out... Well if an open source framework which i don't use myself is causing the problem, it's hard for me to guess :p

Comment: Haha yes. I guess I shouldn't assume that all of these tutorials online are perfect. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I keep on finding that I had other bugs. A HUGE bug I had, which that I had OAConsumer on autorelease, which made my consumer key and secret set to random things like UIImages... Man, going from garbage collection to memory management is tough.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change viewWillAppear like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self testLoc];
}
```

Comment: Still causes the same problem. Argh, I can't tell what's wrong.